# Keyframe animation won't leave

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I just started learning code and so I figured I would start with something simple and include a bunch of styling aspects and animations using keyframes. When one of my animations starts, I have the word 'hello' fading into view and then fading out of view. When the animation is done though, the word hello doesn't completely disappear, it pops into the top left corner of my screen and won't leave. Just curious if anyone knows how to get rid. Like I said, I just started learning so any simple steps would be appreciated. I throw in the code that I currently have.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    .star1{
        border-radius:50%;
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        position:fixed;
        animation-name: flash;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        background:white;
        animation-timing-function:linear;
    }
    .star2{
        border-radius:50%;
        width:15px;
        height:15px;
        position:fixed;
        animation-name: twinkle;
        animation-duration: 2s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        background:white;
        animation-timing-function:linear;
 }
    .star3{
        border-radius:50%;
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        position:fixed;
        animation-name: bright;
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        background:white;
        animation-timing-function:linear;
    }
    .star4{
        border-radius:50%;
        width:10px;
        height:10px;
        position:fixed;
        animation-name: blink;
        animation-duration:2s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        background:white;
        animation-timing-function:ease-out;
    }

    .moon{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 25px 10px 0px 0px white;
    left:350px;
    bottom:300px;
  }

  @keyframes flash{
    0%{
        top:50px; left:100px; opacity:0.5;
    }
    50%{
       top:50px; left:100px; transform:scale(0.5);opacity:.25;
    }
    100%{
        top:50px; left:100px; opacity:0.5;
    }
  }

  @keyframes twinkle{
       0%{
        top:250px; left:300px; opacity:0.5;
    }
    20%{
       top:250px; left:300px; transform:scale(0.5);opacity:.25;
    }
    100%{
        top:250px; left:300px; opacity:0.5;
    }
  }

 @keyframes bright{
       0%{
        top:100px; left:0px; opacity:0.5;
    }
    50%{
       top:125px; left:700px; transform:scale(0.5);opacity:.25;
    }
    100%{
        top:120px; left:700px; transform(0.1); opacity:0;
    }
  }

  @keyframes blink{
       0%{
        top:100px; left:450px; opacity:0.25;
    }
    50%{
       top:100px; left:450px; transform:scale(0.5);opacity:.15;
    }
    100%{
        top:100px; left:450px; opacity:0.25;
    }
}
 .h1{

     font-family:monotype;
     Font-size:120px;
     color:black;
     position:absolute;
     animation-name:words;
     animation-duration:5s;
     animation-iteration-count:1;

 }


 @keyframes words{
     0%{
         top:400px; left:300px; opacity:0;
     }
     50%{
         top:400px; left:300px; opacity:1;
     }
     100%{
         top:400px; left:300px; opacity:0; display:none;
     }
 }
  #back {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(black, #000099, #66c2ff, #ffcccc, #ffeee6);

</style>

<div id="back"></div>
<div class="moon"></div>
<div class="star1"></div>
<div class="star2"></div>
<div class="star3"></div>
<div class="star4"></div>
<div class="h1">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the animation is finished the div only has the properties you've defined on it, so just add `opacity:0;` to `.h1`.

```
   .h1 {
         font-family:monotype;
         Font-size:120px;
         color:black;
         position:absolute;
         animation-name:words;
         animation-duration:5s;
         animation-iteration-count:1;
         opacity:0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `animation-fill-mode` property to your `.h1` class.

```
 .h1{

     font-family:monotype;
     Font-size:120px;
     color:black;
     position:absolute;
     animation-name:words;
     animation-duration:5s;
     animation-iteration-count:1;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }
 @keyframes words{
     0%{
         top:400px; left:300px; opacity:0;
     }
     50%{
         top:400px; left:300px; opacity:1;
     }
     100%{
         top:400px; left:300px; opacity:0; display:none;
     }
 }
```

It is required if you want to kept the state of the last frame after animation is over.

You can also add top, left and opacity to the `.h1` class those defined in the `@keyframes` are now used only when this element is animated.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that somewhere else, but obviously had put it in the wrong place. I appreciate it!